# Java generic collections

Tags: java, generics

I start learning the Java generic collection using Deitel Harvey book - but I am facing a difficulty understanding the three line of codes below - Do all of them perform the same operation on by intializing and adding the relevant values of array ( colors ) to the LinkList variable (list1). How does the second method and third method works - I am having a bit difficulty understanding how Arrays can viewed as a list.. As I know arrays are not dynamic data structure, they have fixed sized length, adding/ removing elements on array can not be done on running time comparing to Lists in general.

```
String[] colors = { "black", "white", "blue", "cyan" };
List< String > list1 = new LinkedList< String >();

// method 1 of initalizing and adding elments to the list
for (String color : colors)
    list1.add(color);

// method 2 of initializing and adding elements to the list
List< String > list1 = new LinkedList< String > (Arrays.asList(colors));

// method 3 of initializing and adding elements to the list
List< String > list1 = Arrays.asList(colors);
```

Please help me understand my queries above, don't judge me as I am still new to this.
Thank you, Sinan

Comment: Not sure I am following, are you asking how are the 2nd and 3rd methods implemented?

Comment: As an aside, is there any reason you're putting spaces around your type arguments, e.g. `List< String >` rather than `List<String>`? The latter is far more conventional.

Comment: Hi Amit, no I am talking about implementation, I simply asking how these methods are viewing Arrays as Lists - I am having difficulty understanding this concept.

Comment: Jon, I simply following the style of the books - please have a look at chapter 20 of Havery Deitel (Java how to program). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you are interested in implementation you can look into certain method. For example, by press *Ctrl+left mouse button* onto method or class.

```
// method 2 of initializing and adding elements to the list
List<String> list1 = new LinkedList<String> (Arrays.asList(colors));
```

This code leads to:

```
List<String> list1 = new LinkedList<String> (new ArrayList<String>(colors));
```

In constructor of `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList(E[] array) {
            if (array==null)
                throw new NullPointerException();
        a = array;
    }
```

the actual array is copied to encapsulated private array field(**link is copied**).

Then in constructor of `LinkedList`:

```
public LinkedList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    this();
    addAll(c);
    }
```

Every element of passed collection is added to the `LinkedList`.

Comment: I got you - this explains a lot - Thank you Yegoshin.

Comment: This answer is misleading -- the `ArrayList` here is not `java.util.ArrayList`

Comment: Its constructor differs from `java.util.ArrayList` and the constructor is shown.

Answer (score 3):

Actually knowledge of generics is not necessary for answering this question.

As you correctly identifier arrays are static in the sense that you can't add elements to them or remove them.

[Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html), however, usually allow those operations.

The `List` returned by [`Arrays.asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) *does* have the [`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29)/[`remove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) methods (otherwise it would not be a valid `List`). *However* actually *calling* those methods will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` exactly **because** you can't actually add elements to an array (for which this `List` is simply a view/wrapper).

Operations that *don't* structurally modify the list (i.e. that don't change the number of elements in the list) are entirely possible: [`set(int, E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set%28int,%20E%29) works just fine on the `List` returned by `Arrays.asList()`.

Comment: Thank you Joachim, I still don't understand how Arrays are viewed as List ? I probably can not think of it in a logical way. how on earth are viewing something static in behavior to dynamic...

Comment: @Sinan: not all `List` objects are identical. Some allow only read-only access (see [`Collections.unmodifiableList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)), others allow all operations (your average `ArrayList`), ...).

Comment: Arrays.asList creates an instance of a private class Arrays$ArrayList which happens to extend AbstractList.  It does not however override the methods which would modify the size (ie, add, remove, etc...).  The default implementations of those in AbstractList is to throw an UnsupportedOperationException.  The view methods (get, toArray) are implemented such that they directly access the array given in the constructor.  It's a classic application of the "adapter" pattern used here.

Comment: And don't confuse the private Arrays$ArrayList with the class java.util.ArrayList

Answer (score 2):

`Arrays.asList` returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.

It is actually a bridge between Array and Collection framework. But returned list write through to the array.

Answer (score 2):

Only your first method does anything to the `LinkedList` you have initially assigned into `list1`. The other two assign a new, unrelated list to it. The third option assigns something that isn't a `LinkedList`, but a special implementation of the `List` interface backed by your String array. In the third case you won't be able to add/remove elements from the list, but you can iterate over it and update existing slots. Basically, it does what a plain array does, just through the `List` interface.

Comment: Thank you Marko for your reply. I am still can not how arrays are viewed as Lists - what is the magic behind to let it behave this way? do you have any idea how ? Thank you.

Comment: No magic, really. `ArrayList` uses an array internally as well. If you are interested, you can easily check the code at grepcode.com. Google for `grepcode java.util.Arrays`.

Comment: Thank you for your time Marko. I will look through it.

Answer (score 1):

[`Arrays.asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) creates a List from an Array. Arrays in general can't be viewed as lists in Java. They can only be wrapped in a list.

So method 2 is used to have a specific list implementation `LinkedList` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

to Method 2, just check the Api here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#LinkedList(java.util.Collection)
For sure, Lists implement the Collections Interface so this Constructor will work here.

to Method 3, just check out the Api here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)

Answer (score 0):

if you see the link below
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#LinkedList%28java.util.Collection%29

you will see the constructor of linked list class which is accepting a collection object as parameter.

Any in your post, the 2nd and 3 rd lines are passing an object of collection class(i.e Arrays.asList is finally giving a List which is a sub class of collection).

So both 2nd and 3rd lines fairly valid implementations.
More over you can observe one more good coding practice in all the 3 lines.
That is

> writing code to interceptors than to classes

. (referring

> LinkedList

instance with

> List

interface)

Always try to refer your classes with interceptors which is a good practice